# WCF Service - how to protect so only my clients can use it?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I am building a client program that interacts with a WCF Service via Internet. Everything works as intended but I am wondering how I can protect my services so that only my client program can make use of it?

Right now everyone with the correct URL to my services can use it with WCFTestClient (e.g).

What is the best way to make it private so only my clients can make use of the service? Rotating token strings? Certificate? Password?

I have no idea and haven't found anything useful on the Internet.

Best regards

UPDATE: The client program is intended to be downloaded for the public (everyone). So it is not for internal use, it will be a service we are gonna provide, ones in official production.

My own thinking was like: Bind a certificate in my client programs (if thats possible even?). On the IIS where the WCF service is running, check for valid certificate. Is that possible? Or better solutions out there?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163570.aspx

Comment: In IIS you can enable it so only a known IP of a client or IP range can call it. A long with SSL, credentials etc listed below

Comment: Hi Kyle, sorry my I was not specific enough. The client program, ones in production, should be for everyone. So I don't know the IP addresses of the clients. I basically want it that way, that my client has some kind of authentication against the service, so the services are locked down for public/guests.

Comment: The problem with most security / credential mechanisms is that they are focussed on the user, not the client program. E.g. certificates have to be installed in at least the user's certificate store and can therefore be used by any other program. You could use passwords, but this might not be safe enough. The question is, why do you want to constrain client programs? A good web service should be available to any client without having to rely on their behaviour.

Comment: Nico> Because the clients will interact with the WCF service. Uploading data and downloading data. Why would I want anyone outside messing with my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Protect .net Web Service URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2598763/protect-net-web-service-url)

Along with the other answers, that can't be bad too,
and if you want to be super careful you can implement a token system, where the clients get the first token from you, each request returns a new token, and you always check a client vs it's current token (but that's being over careful in my opinion)

Update - because it's for the public, the client can have a way of generating a valid token to check on the server, you can have a token be valid for an interval of seconds, so even if people caught the request and found the token, it will not be valid after ..15 seconds or 30,etc

Comment: Hi Royi, I also thought of the idea of the token. But I have a question about that. Would I then have to pass the token in every method I use with the WCF service? Or is there another way to implement it?

Comment: You make a token generator, based on time - or based on something that's changing but is still the same in the client and server, and you pass that token with each request, it even can be and should be dependent on client info, the server just generates the same token and checks both tokens. but yes, you will have to send the token with every request :)

Comment: Okay, thank you very much Royi. That is was I thought. I was hoping for a smarter way though :D

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Form Authentication then you can leverage the ASP.NET to check for FormAuthentication Cookie by enabling AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode to Required

Or if your service is stand alone i.e is consumed by everyone then you can use oauth authentication you can read more about it [Oauth Authentication](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/523/oauth-dot-net)

What you could do is there would be a consumer secret key which would be shared to all authenticated clients. The caller would sign some info using this key and server would also sign it using the same key and then compare it.

Hope it helps